# Cleanest way to convert a float to uint

Tags: c

I have a float value that should take only values between -40 and +120. For a given data transmission function I need to convert that to a uint16 (or two uint8). What is the cleanest way to map this limited decimal range to all possible values of uint16?

Thus, if the float is < -40, the uint16 value should be 0, if the float is > 120 it is 65535 and if in range, just the linear relation (thus increments of ~0.0024).

Comment: Each value in the 16-bit integer will correspond to `161.0 / 65536.0` (about `0.0025` as you noticed). So first you need to zero-offset the input value (i.e. add `40`) and then divide by `161.0 / 65536.0` to get the corresponding integer value. That's the mathematical solution anyway, but it won't give you the exact values you might hope for (except for `-40.0` which will indeed be `0`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `(120.0+40.0) / (161.0/65536) != 65535` as required.  should be `160.0/65535.0`.  Clearly you have provided an answer - why post int as a comment?

Answer (score 2):

Test for the limit (saturation) cases, then when in range the value is:

> *(f + 40)/160 * 65535*

That is just simple arithmetic.

```
uint16_t int_val = 0 ;
if( float_val < -40.0f )
{
    int_val = 0 ;
}
else if( float_val > 120.0f )
{
    int_val = 0xFFFF ;
}
else
{
    int_val = (uint16_t)((float_val + 40.0f) / 160.0f * (float)0xFFFF) ; 
}
```

Comment: Rather than a simple cast, it might be better to use `floorf`, `ceilf`, or `nearbyintf` (or `truncf`, `roundf`, or `lrintf`), depending on how you want to round the values.

Comment: @SGeorgiades some of those options might result in a value greater 65535.  It is not a matter of preference - there is only one correct rounding if you want a valid solution to the stated requirements.  Point taken though, there are other solutions.  You should perhaps post and answer and explain why it would be preferred.

Comment: Actually, @Clifford, none of those would result in values greater than 65535 because you've already tested for edge cases. And there is NOT only one correct way to round; it's a question of whether it is preferred that the rounded values are slightly larger or slightly smaller than the true value would be.

Comment: @SGeorgiades agreed - on reflection.  Computationally this is simpler, but with the maximum peak quantisation error.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my slightly different version of the above:

```
uint16_t convert(float fval)
{
    if (fval < -40) return(0);
    if (fval > 120) return(UINT16_MAX);
    return(lrintf((fval + 40) / 160 * UINT16_MAX);
}
```

If you prefer, you can use `floorf` or `ceilf` instead of `lrintf`, depending on your rounding preferences.

Note that for `UINT16_MAX` to be defined, you'll have to include `stdint.h`.

Comment: SO orders answers by votes/acceptance.  Referencing the answer "above" may not hold.

Comment: Why would you not want a "naked number"? And I don't know what you mean by "half-dressed".

Comment: You do not need parentheses around the value being returned in a `return` statement. `return 0;` suffices. `return(0);` is cluttered. And the last statement does not have balanced parentheses.